# Issue with CNN Model for Spectrogram Reconstruction in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working on a project to reconstruct audio spectrograms using a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) in Keras. The goal is to input a spectrogram to the model and have it output a reconstructed version of the same spectrogram. My dataset consists of spectrograms extracted from audio files. Each spectrogram is a 2D array with a shape of (1876, 1025). The dataset has 10 such spectrograms. I've split this data into a training set with 8 spectrograms and a validation set with 2 spectrograms.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(1876, 1025, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

# Reshape and upsample to original dimensions
model.add(Dense(32 * 469 * 256, activation='relu'))  # Adjust this dimension appropriately
model.add(Reshape((469, 256, 32)))  # Adjust to match the shape before flattening

model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation='relu'))

# Final layer - ensure the output shape matches the input shape
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
# Notice that X_train is used as both the input and the target
history = model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val, X_val))

# Evaluate the model
val_loss = model.evaluate(X_val, X_val)
print("Validation Loss:", val_loss)
```

Problem:
I am encountering an issue with reshaping and upsampling layers in the model. The error message I receive is related to incompatible shapes during training. Specifically, it seems like there's a mismatch between the model's output shape and the input shape.

How should I correctly set the parameters of the Dense and Reshape layers to ensure the output shape matches the input spectrograms? Are there adjustments I need to make in the Conv2DTranspose layers to achieve the correct output shape? Any general advice on structuring the CNN for this kind of reconstruction task would be highly appreciated.

I have already normalized the data and converted the wav files into a spectrogram as seen in the following code:

```
# Define your base data directory
base_data_dir = '/content/data'
processed_data_dir = os.path.join(base_data_dir, 'processed')
sampling_rate = 96000  # Desired sampling rate

# Feature extraction function to obtain spectrograms
def extract_features(audio_path, sr=sampling_rate):
    data, _ = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=sr)
    S = librosa.stft(data)
    spectrogram = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(S), ref=np.max)
    return spectrogram

# Function to visualize a spectrogram
def visualize_spectrogram(spectrogram, sr=sampling_rate):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    librosa.display.specshow(spectrogram, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
    plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
    plt.title('Spectrogram')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Initialize a list to collect spectrograms
spectrograms_list = []

# Loop over each file and extract the spectrogram
for filename in os.listdir(processed_data_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'):
        processed_audio_path = os.path.join(processed_data_dir, filename)
        spectrogram = extract_features(processed_audio_path)
        spectrograms_list.append(spectrogram.T)  # Transpose to align time to columns

# Convert the list of spectrograms to a 3D NumPy array
spectrograms_array = np.array(spectrograms_list)

print("Shape of the 'spectrograms_array':", spectrograms_array.shape)

# Visualize the first few spectrograms from the array
for i in range(min(5, len(spectrograms_array))):  # Adjust this number based on how many spectrograms you want to see
    visualize_spectrogram(spectrograms_array[i].T, sr=sampling_rate)
```